# javafx Pagination memory leak when replacing buttons

Tags: java, memory-leaks, javafx, pagination, java-8

I first noticed this by having a huge memory leak caused by resizing javafx.scene.control.Pagination.

I created a sample app to show the behavior. Every click on any button causes more memory to be consumed. I suppose that the correct way to deal with this is to remove any listeners on the ToggleButtons before clearing them but PaginationSkin isn't doing that.

Have I missed something or is this a real bug in the Pagination code?

Are there any workarounds?

The same behavior is seen it both 8u40 and 8u45. I haven't tried any older versions yet.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ToggleGroupLeak extends Application {

    private HBox hbox;
    private ToggleGroup toggleGroup;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        hbox = new HBox();
        redo();

        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 100));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void redo() {
        hbox.getChildren().clear();
        toggleGroup.getToggles().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            addButton(i);
        }
    }

    private void addButton(final int i) {
        ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton("" + i);
        btn.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        btn.setOnAction(e -> redo());
        hbox.getChildren().add(btn);
    }
}
```

Concretely, usage of Pagination in an AnchorPane seems to cause the same leak by resizing the control.

FXML

```
<Pagination fx:id="pagination" visible="true" AnchorPane.topAnchor="3.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="130.0"/>
```

Java

```
@FXML
protected Pagination pagination;

// Init method run once
    pagination.setMaxPageIndicatorCount(100);
    pagination.currentPageIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldPageIndex, newPageIndex) -> {
        if (!oldPageIndex.equals(newPageIndex)) {
            if (searchParams.getPage() == newPageIndex.intValue()) {
                return;
            }

            searchParams.setPage(newPageIndex.intValue());
            // Code that inits the new page
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Added pagination specific code

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption? What is your evidence the GC simply hasn't needed to run?

Comment: Using jvisualvm, hitting the gui to "Perform GC". The same behavior has been seen on ubuntu and osx

Comment: Looks like something is getting retained. I'm not sure removing the listeners will help though; have you verified that? It's more likely that the toggle group is the problem: try calling `toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();`  in your `redo()` method above. It still behaves a little strangely, but does appear to (*eventually*) reclaim the memory.

Comment: Indeed, creating a new ToggleGroup every time let's the garbage collect the whole old ToggleGroup with listeners, etc. This points to the ToggleGroup being the problem. I still need a workaround for Pagination though, where I can't control the creation/release of the togglegroups without being too intrusive.

Comment: Impossible to really help with that since we don't see you pagination code. But can you not encapsulate the toggle group with the node that is created by the page factory?

Comment: I've briefly looked through the pagination code lib nad found the PaginationSkin class, which creates (one) ToggleGroup and ToggleButtons without factories. I'd have to replace the whole skin then...